# How to force Steam Games to load libraries from Steam Folders

Tags: games, steam

Recently I bought Dead Island but it seems like Dead Island would give you a black screen. So I went to the console and run `./DeadIslandGame from`~/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Dead Island`. This is what it gave me:

```
./DeadIslandGame: error while loading shared libraries: libSDL2-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

A bit of investigation revealed that there are libSDL2 libraries both in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` (since I tried to do `sudo apt install libSDL2*`) and also in `.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.old/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/`.

My question is how can I make Dead Island run since I'm guessing the problem here is that DI is missing its libraries. However I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special. Running games from within Steam runs them with the libraries provided by the Steam client.

However, when you run things manually on the CLI in this manner, the environment is not set up to use the Steam Runtime. The reason you got the missing library error, is because you don't have the `i386` version of the libraries installed, but you are attempting to run a 32-bit program.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you will need to issue this

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

to enable 32 bit libraries to get installed ... then try a re-install of DI to pickup missing libs